# Can't run .jar file on my symbian cell phone

Tags: symbian

I try to install .jar files on my Nokia X6 but I just doesn't do anything. I looked for a solution on many sites, but the only solution I found was running a jarfix.exe which obviously can be executed on windows OS not on my symbian. I really appreciate if you can help me on this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the JAR-file is compatible with the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Not all JAR files are compatible with mobile phones.  Are you trying to install a J2SE program?  That won't work.